# Wrong (maxTouchPoints) and ('ontouchstart' in document) in Chrome mobile emulation mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, touch, emulation

I use a touchscreen device detection like this:

```
if (window.navigator.maxTouchPoints || 'ontouchstart' in document)  
    // handle as mobile device
else
    // handle as desktop
```

When I change the screen in Chrome mobile emulation the result of both `maxTouchPoints`  and `'ontouchstart' in document` is unpredictable.

For one and same emulated screen it may return `maxTouchPoints` equals to 0 or 1, and  `'ontouchstart' in document` equals to `true` or `false`.

So, I cannot really on this check.
Could you recommend a way to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug so maybe you could report it on https://crbug.com. As for a solution, I suggest using a real emulator app, and connect your desktop Chrome to its mobile Chrome by using ADB over network (it's either built-in or there are mobile apps that enable it).

Answer (score 3):

I created following function that checks if touch points are actually enabled (for example, using the "enable touch points button" on device/emulator):

```
function isTouchEventsEnabled() {
    // Bug in FireFox+Windows 10, navigator.maxTouchPoints is incorrect when script is running inside frame.
    // TBD: report to bugzilla.
    const navigator = (window.top || window).navigator;
    const maxTouchPoints = Number.isFinite(navigator.maxTouchPoints) ? navigator.maxTouchPoints : navigator.msMaxTouchPoints;
    if (Number.isFinite(maxTouchPoints)) {
        // Windows 10 system reports that it supports touch, even though it acutally doesn't (ignore msMaxTouchPoints === 256).
        return maxTouchPoints > 0 && maxTouchPoints !== 256;
    }
    return 'ontouchstart' in window;
}
```

Comment: Must add a try..catch. Otherways it crashes in some browsers:

Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.ohmydots.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Answer (score 2):

I just upgraded Chrome to version 101.0.4951.67 and now this problem appears.

You may get over it by using

`let maxTouchPoints = navigator.maxTouchPoints & 0xFF;`

or by using a shim:

```js
let descriptor = navigator.platform === 'Win32' ? 
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Navigator.prototype, 'maxTouchPoints') : null;
if(descriptor && descriptor.get){
  Object.defineProperty(Navigator.prototype, 'maxTouchPoints', {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    get: function(){
      return descriptor.get.call(this) & 0xFF;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What does & 0xFF check for ? 

1st solution fixed issue for me where I have no touchscreen but chrome is returning maxTouchPoints=256

Comment: My laptop contains no touchscreen but Windows/Chrome reports `navigator.maxTouchPoints` as 256, so I need to regard that 256 as 0. `& 0xFF` is to coerce a number to uint8 (0~255), thus `256 & 0xFF` equals 0.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
function isTouchscreen() {
  return ("ontouchstart" in window) || (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) ? true : false;
}

if (isTouchscreen()) {
  console.log('IS touchscreen');}
else {
  console.log('IS NOT touchscreen');
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/maxTouchPoints

Comment: MaxTouchPoints should be lowercase: navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0