# navigator.maxTouchPoints = 256 on desktop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, touch

I rly dont know what to do anymore.

If I run this js:

```
    console.log(navigator.maxTouchPoints);
```

I get 256 as answer on my DESKTOP

- I tested it on chrome and FireFox (both latest version).
- I resetted chrome
- I made new VsCode project with same code

nothing helped

Any ideas what is wrong with my pc?

[image of FireFox running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgIm6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug with Windows 10 and Firefox. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67909182/5507624) for a workaround. Although the answer mentions it, I wasn't able to find a reported bug on BugZilla yet.

Comment: I had the same issue on Windows 11 (multiple browsers), resolved after a reboot. I've reported it here: https://aka.ms/AAg70b4.

Comment: also happens with Chrome Version 114.0.5735.199